# Find OracleClientFactory type from GAC

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

The `Type.GetType` method should find me a type in the GAC if I specify an assembly-qualified name. Here's what I did:

```
Type factoryType = Type.GetType("System.Data.OracleClient.OracleClientFactory, System.Data.OracleClient");
```

But `factoryType` is always null.

Maybe I could specify a fully-qualified name instead, including PublicKey and all that, but I don't know the necessary details, and they're different for every .NET framework version. I wanted to avoid that and make it run everywhere.

I cannot use a compiler assembly reference because the code can be configured at runtime and may not be used at all. I also know that the requested type is obsolete but it's still there and may be used when other alternatives are not available.

I'm targeting the .NET framework versions from 4.0 to 4.5, later also 4.6.

Comment: If the assembly has a strong name, a complete assembly name is required (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx)). Could you describe why you cann't use an assembly reference?

Comment: My application can be used with different database systems (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle...) and it can be configured at runtime what backend should be used. If another Oracle provider like Devart dotConnect can be used, this one is not required. But it should be available as a fallback. I'm not sure it's a good idea to have an assembly reference to this if a better one is available when deployed.

Comment: Then you can use answer provided by @rene. The fully qualified name for OracleClientFactory is the same for all framework versions you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really, really, really need to do that you can still use the [LoadWithPartialName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12xc5368(v=vs.110).aspx) overload

```
var factory = Assembly
         .LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.OracleClient")
         .GetType("System.Data.OracleClient.OracleClientFactory");
```

but note that it is already declared **obsolete** which is one step closer to **deprecated**. With obsolete is still compiles with warnings.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but wouldn't  it be easier to add all possible factories to the [config file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="SqlClient Data Provider"
     invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" 
     type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, 
     Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

and then iterate over your connnectionstrings to find the provider you need?